# Shall jarrayObject (array of strings) be deleted/released after usage in a JNI call ?

Tags: java, c++, memory-management, java-native-interface

I'm experimenting in C++ with JNI and have a doubt about what to do with Java object that I've created in C++ for being used as JNI call argument.

Take this very simple java class, with a string array argument:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World in java");
        int i; 
        for (i=0; i<args.length; i++)
            System.out.println(args[i]);        
    }
}
```

I call it from C++ with the following JNI code:

```
jmethodID mid3 = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls2, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V"); // signature for String array arg.
if(mid3 == nullptr) 
    cerr << "ERROR: method not found !" << endl;
else {
     jobjectArray arr = env->NewObjectArray(5,   // constructs java array of 5
             env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),
                env->NewStringUTF("str"));   // with this default value
     env->SetObjectArrayElement(             // change one of the array elements
             arr, 1, env->NewStringUTF("MYOWNSTRING"));
     env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls2, mid3, arr); // call method
}
```

This works very well.  But I'm unsure what I have to to with the jarrayObject (and the java strings it contains) afterwards, to keep the things clean.

My understanding would be that the JVM is responsible for the java objects.  But how does it know which objectsz I no longer need on the C++ side ?  I googled around and didn't find any clear explanation.  I read in the [JNI specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local) for `DeleteLocalRef()` that:

> Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call.
>   They are freed automatically after the native method returns.

So shall I call `DeleteLocalRef()` for the jarrayObject  (or even for every java string it contains) or some other cleaning function ? Or can I assume that JVM takes care of this on its own ?

Comment: JVM will take care about this object because the object is allocated on Java heap this heap will be managed by JVM and when GC occurs it will release all objects if there is no reference to them. Hope this helps

Comment: @DucVo But then, if I start to create some java objects in advance and the GC is called during one of JNI invocation, the JVM could scratch my objects before they are used, isn't it ?

Comment: Actually, before GC occurs it suspends all threads or wait threads to be finished and then proceed to check and clarify all dereference objects and collect them after that it will resume those threads. In your case, I think the GC will wait for JNI invocation finished and it will suspend your thread and start the collection at this context if the object still be referenced so the GC will mark it as alive (e.g without collecting it) otherwise it will collect it.

Answer (score 2):

The [jni design specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html) (see section ***Global and local references***) explains  that:

- all references passed to a native method as well as all references returned by JNI functions are local references;
- these local references are automatically freed after the native method returns.

However, this principle applies only to the case of a C++ function called by Java:  the local references are released when the function returns to Java (see section ***Implementing local references***).

If you create objects or get references from JNI functions in C++ code that is not called from Java, the local references ARE NOT FREED AUTOMATICALLY, causing memory to leak.

So you should better use `DeleteLocalRef()` to free java objects created/obtained from C++ but no longer used.

### Demonsration:

The following simple **Java code** allocates big objects without keeping their references, and call some memory inspection:

```
class BigMemoryConsumer {
    private char myTable[];   

    public BigMemoryConsumer () {   // Allocate and use 1Mb 
        myTable = new char[1048576];
        for (int i=0; i<1048576; i++) 
            myTable[i] = (char) (i % 256);  
    }
    
    public static long showMem() {  // Show memory statistics 
        int funit = 1024*1024;
        String unit =  " Mb"; 
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.gc();    // opportunity to run garbage collector (not guaranteed !)  
        long used = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Used Memory:  " + used / funit + unit 
            + " ("+ (used*100/runtime.maxMemory())+"%)");
        System.out.println("Free Memory:  " + runtime.freeMemory() / funit + unit);
        System.out.println("Total Memory: " + runtime.totalMemory() / funit + unit);
        System.out.println("Max Memory:   " + runtime.maxMemory() / funit + unit);
        System.out.println("");
        return used;   
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {     // test in java
        long lastmem = showMem(); 
        for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
            BigMemoryConsumer m = new BigMemoryConsumer(); 
            long mem = showMem(); 
            if (mem<=lastmem) {
                System.out.println ("Garbage collector freed some memory"); 
                return; 
            }
            else lastmem = mem;
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this class directly from **Java** (aka `main()`)  You'll notice that Java will very quicly (second or third iteration on my 64bit system) run the garbage collector: the object m is reinitialised on every iteration, meaning that previously created objects are no longer referenced.

Now I've reproduced the equivalent `main()` in **C++ code**, just after having loaded the JVM and initialized the JNI environment:

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("BigMemoryConsumer");
jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");    // find consructor 
jmethodID show = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "showMem", "()J");  // find memShow() 

jlong lastmem = 0;
vector<jobject> v;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    jobject myo = env->NewObject(cls, ctor);
    v.push_back(myo);
    jlong mem = env->CallStaticLongMethod(cls, show);
    if(mem <= lastmem) {
        cout << "ATTENTION:  garbage collector called as consumed java memory didn't increase after "<<i<<" iterations\n";
        break;
    }
    else lastmem = mem;
    //env->DeleteLocalRef(myo); ///!!!! <======= SEE TEXT 
}
```

If running the code without the `DeleteLocalRef()`, you'll notice a continuous increase in consumed memory:  no garbage collection takes place, as the JVM is not aware that the reference to the java object requested from C++ is no longe used.

If you comment out the highlighted line, the  `DeleteLocalRef()` will tell the JVM that the object is no longer needed in the C++ code, and the garbage collector will behave exactly as in the pure java example,  rfreeing up the object after a couple of iterations.