# JNI to running process instead of using a library

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I have some image recognition software running to generate input for my game.
I detect movements through openCV in C++, however a constraint is that the game itself should be written in java.I would like to query the state of the openCV process to get some objects for input. I wanted to do this through JNI calls to my running process, but all JNI examples simply call library functions, not to a running process. so is this possible through JNI or am i forced to use sockets for this?

Comment: I don't really understand what "JNI to my running process" means -- if you want to do a cross-process call, you need to use IPC (such as sockets).  It looks like you got a good answer though, so maybe you can ask the answerer to edit your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the JVM from C++, initialize your openCV based components and then run the java code.

The basics of the invocation is explaned [here, with a sample snippet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html).  For an example to launch a Java component via a static method, you can look at the code at [the end of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30311328/3723423).

Finally for calling your C++ monitoring function, you have to use a native method in your java code, and register a c++ function for it.  This function may then access everything you prepared during initialization.  Example:

In Java:

```
class MyTest {
    ...
    public native void doMonitor();  // to be supplied in C++ trhough JNI 
}
```

In C++, somewhere in your initialisation code (before you launch the Java code), you have to register the native method:

```
    jclass cls2 = env->FindClass("MyTest");
    JNINativeMethod methods[] { { "doMonitor", "()V", (void *)&doMonitorCPP } };
    if(env->RegisterNatives(cls2, methods, 1) < 0)
    {
        if(env->ExceptionOccurred())
            cerr << " OOOOOPS: exception when registreing natives" << endl; 
        else
            cerr << " ERROR: problem when registreing naives" << endl;
    }
```

`doMonitor()` would be defined for example like:

```
void doMonitorCPP(JNIEnv*e, jobject o) {
    std::cout << "C++callback activated" << std::endl;
    // do what you need to do with openCV. 
}
```